# Difference between the design pattern and anti-pattern

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

I'm reading the theory about designing software architecture and I see there are some theories such as SOLID principles, Design Pattern and Anti-Pattern that we should consider when we design our software.

**My Question:** What are the differences between the Design Pattern and Anti-Pattern and what problem they solve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple Difference would be:

**Design Patterns:**

Solutions which are productive and efficient and are developed by Software Engineers over the years of practice and solving problems.

**Anti Patterns:**

Known solutions which are actually bad or defective to certain kind of problems.

From Wikipedia:

> An anti-pattern is a common response to a recurring problem that is
>   usually ineffective and risks being highly counterproductive.[1][2]
>   The term, coined in 1995 by Andrew Koenig,[3] was inspired by a book,
>   Design Patterns, which highlights a number of design patterns in
>   software development that its authors considered to be highly reliable
>   and effective.
>
> The term was popularized three years later by the book AntiPatterns,
>   which extended its use beyond the field of software design to refer
>   informally to any commonly reinvented but bad solution to a problem.
>   Examples include analysis paralysis, cargo cult programming, death
>   march, groupthink and vendor lock-in.

Example of some anti patterns:

1. https://javaantipatterns.wordpress.com/
2. https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns

Hope this makes sense.